# Struggling with using iteration and println in Julia

Tags: iteration, julia

I am new to Julia and trying to understand how things work.

Below is the sample code I just wrote.

(This is the baseline code and I am planning to add other lines one by one.)

I expected to see something like 1 2 3 4 5 6 7... from test = check(m)

However, I don't see any result.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

```
using Pkg
using Optim
using Printf
using LinearAlgebra, Statistics
using BenchmarkTools, Optim, Parameters, QuantEcon, Random
using Optim: converged, maximum, maximizer, minimizer, iterations
using Interpolations
using Distributions
using SparseArrays
using Roots
  
# ================ 1. Parameters and Constants ============================

mutable struct Model    
    # Model Parameters and utility function
    δ::Float64
    function Model(;
        δ = 0.018,
        )
        new(
        δ
        )
    end
end

function check(m)
    
    it = 0
    tol=1e-8
    itmax = 1000
    dif = 0

    # Iteration
    while it < itmax && dif >=tol
        it = it + 1;
        V = Vnew;
        println(it)
    end      
    return itmax
end

m=Model()
test = check(m)
```

Comment: Is `0` greater than `1e-8`? If not, then your loop will never run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dif = 0
tol = 1e-8

while it < itmax && dif >= tol
```

Now explain to me how
dif >= tol

Comment: Is this an answer? If so, it could do with some clarification. It *looks* like you're saying that dif starts off less than tol so the condition for the while isn't met, but that isn't obvious from what you've written.

Comment: Is that comment out of date? It looks like you edited the answer. Is it fixed?